# How to toggle column visiblity in table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any simple way to toggle visiblity of one column in a table?
I know I can use jQuery and write some code to do this, but I think there's much simplier way to do this.

Comment: You use Bootstrap which depends on jQuery, so why shouldn't you use jQuery?

Comment: You could use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428480/is-it-possible-to-hide-show-table-columns-by-changing-the-css-class-on-the-col

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap 3 is a class `.hidden`. You can add this class to the column, wich shouldn't be visible.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bla1<td>
    <td>Bla1<td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="hidden">    //This column is now  hidden
    <td>Bla2<td>
    <td>Bla2<td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bla3<td>
    <td>Bla3<td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: I want to toggle column not row