# Table: "visibility:collapse" does not work with "border-collapse"

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I am trying to hide columns in a table using `<col>` and `visibility:collapse` as described here:
[Is it possible to hide / show table columns by changing the CSS class on the col element only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428480/is-it-possible-to-hide-show-table-columns-by-changing-the-css-class-on-the-col)

Now I found out that this solution seems to work only with "normal" tables but not when having `border-collapse:collapse`. In that case, only the content of the column is hidden and the content of the subsequent columns is shifted to the left.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/seeLcc2p/3/

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*   border-collapse:separate; */
}

.hide {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
      /* css code */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="50" class="hide" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 1 Col 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 2 Col 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
      <td>Row 3 Col 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

When having `border-collapse:separate;` everything is as excepted, with `border-collapse:collapse;` the layout is broken…

Any ideas how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong?
Tried in Firefox 57.0.4.

Comment: Looks like a Firefox bug. Note that Chrome doesn't support visibility:collapse on columns at all. I suggest you check Edge and if it looks as you expect then file a bug against Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using visibility:collapse, try visibility:hidden it should do the trick

Comment: These are different. visibility:hidden will leave a blank space where the column used to be, while visibility:collapse will not.